# Replace List in Json Object Function

Tags: python, list, function, replace

I have been playing with

Below is my code:

```
def extract_info(msg):
    created_time = msg['created_time'].replace('T', ' ').replace('+0000', '')
    mess = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8') 
    message = (mess[:498] + '..') if len(mess) > 498 else mess
    user_id = msg['from']['id']
    return (created_time, message, user_id)



def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('dishwasher')
    js = json.loads(data)
    messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('data', []))
    write_csv('fb_dishwasher.csv', messages, append=True)
```

Problems with the above code:

I want to manipulate 'message' by using an ignore list through a replace.

Kinda what I want to do:

```
ignore = ["you","all","has","can","that", "the", "what", "with", "and", "to", "this", "would","from", "your", "which", "while", "these", "when", "way", "like", "been", "will", "look"]

def replaceall(s, olds, replacement):
    for old in olds:
        s = s.replace(old, replacement)
    return s
```

The big problem is I am not sure how to blend in the above ignore list into my existing function for 'extract_info' above.  Do I make a new function or do I make a nested function with in the existing one. (which doesn't feel right).  I would really like to some ideas and thoughts about the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: You already seem to have the replacement function, which can be called in the extract_info function as such. What is the issue? Maybe the question in not clear to me.

Comment: How do you want to "manipulate message by using the ignore list"? How should message change? Should those words be removed? Please provide an example.

Comment: The words in the ignore list should be removed.  For example: "Go to the store"  would be "Go store"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem that extract_info gets a **single** message each time, maybe you better use e function there instead of doing relaceall to all messages at once, i.e:

```
message = message.replace(old, replacement)
```

Comment: I think this may be the best approach. Thanks Guy!!